# How to use an external database from my application in Minikube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

i have a problem, I can't connect to an external database that is in my same network but in another node. My application is built on spring boot and my problem is trying to connect to the database. This is the stacktrace of the error.

```
    22:40:56.393 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
22:41:07.480 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
22:41:07.482 [main] WARN  o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
```

I'm using minikube version: v1.26.0
Code for start minikube:

```
minikube start --driver=hyperkit
```

My deployment yml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-application
spec:
  selector:
    role: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-gastronomia
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: webapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: webapp
        env: production
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-gastronomia
          image: localhost:5000/app-gastronomia:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jre-slim
COPY build/libs/register-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8001
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

In docker everything works fine, I have no problem.

Ping from ubuntu pod

```
root@ubuntu:/# ping -c 3 172.16.0.180
PING 172.16.0.180 (172.16.0.180) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 172.16.0.180 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2072ms
```

Ping from my computer's terminal

```
ping -c 3 172.16.0.180                                                                                                                          2 ✘  took 13s   at 05:47:45 PM  
PING 172.16.0.180 (172.16.0.180): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.16.0.180: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=78.136 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.180: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=74.404 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.180: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=74.904 ms

--- 172.16.0.180 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 74.404/75.815/78.136/1.654 ms
```

Investigating, create a service and endpoint pointing to the external ip, here my file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
      protocol: TCP
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.16.0.180
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

Doing a ping from the ubuntu pod

```
root@ubuntu:/# ping -c 3 database
    PING database.default.svc.cluster.local (172.16.0.180) 56(84) bytes of data.
    
    --- database.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
    3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2032ms
```

Any solution on how to connect from my application (pod) to the minikube database outside?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I work from home, I access the database from a vpn

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you've set up Minikube. Normally, it is running inside a VM which is isolated from the network other local containers are running on.
There are 2 simple ways you can go about to solve your issue -

1. Run the DB on Minikube as well, which will allow the application to access it using k8s internal dns address
2. Expose the DB to the public internet using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com) or a similar solution. This approach is much less recommended as it needlessly exposes your DB to the internet just so you can access it from Minikube.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention that I work from home, I access the database from a vpn, can that be a problem? and another question, what would be the best configuration to start minikube for this case?

Comment: I thought the db is running locally on your machine, is it hosted on a remote server?

Comment: Yes, that's right, in fact I work from home and the database is in the company where I work

Comment: In that case, it's strange that Minikube can't access the DB. Not sure how the VPN is configured so it's hard to tell what should be changed.

Comment: Hello, I was able to solve it using virtualbox, thanks and regards!

Comment: @hectoralvarezperez : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Hello, sure, just use this setting to start minikube minikube start --driver=virtualbox , I think it's because virtualbox uses network nat, and makes minikube run on the same network as my home. I left all the other configuration as it was, without touching anything and everything worked without problems